# Asp.Net Microsoft Identity and OAuth and OpenId

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Microsoft Identity is Microsoft's framework for generating authentication.

My question is what is the relationship between Microsoft Identity and OAuth and OpenId ?.

Are Aouth and OpenId implemented in Microsoft Identity ?.

How can we use OAuth and OpenId with Microsoft Identity?

Thank you for the answer

Comment: Too vague but this might help you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=996OiexHze0

Answer (score 1):

[image]
Please check Microsoft documentation here.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols

You can use identityserver4 which is built on top of oauth and openid.

Comment: You didn't explain the relationship between Microsoft Identity, Oauth, and OpenId.

Comment: OpenID Connect (OIDC) is an authentication protocol built on OAuth 2.0 that you can use to securely sign in a user to an application. When you use the Microsoft identity platform endpoint's implementation of OpenID Connect, you can add sign-in and API access to your apps. OpenID uses OAuth 2.0 authorization protocol for use as an authentication protocol, so that you can do single sign-on using OAuth. OpenID Connect introduces the concept of an ID token, which is a security token that allows the client to verify the identity of the user. The ID token also gets basic profile of the user.

Comment: How can we use OpenId with Asp.net and how can we also use OAuth with Asp.net? are they used together ? or each technology used seperately ?

Comment: OpenID is built using OAthu2.0 and Microsoft Identity uses OpenID. They are tied up together. Normally when user request a secured page from app server, identity server prompts credentials from user via a page from identity server (i.e. login page), generate id_token and send back to browser with redirect URI. Browser redirect to that URI, validates and send secure page to user. The identity server provided by Microsoft in Azure, use this identity server for multiple apps (i.e. asp.net app, android, java etc). You can build your own identity server app as well.

Comment: 1.  Identity app issues token (if you dont have it, you can use microsoft's in azure), send to other apps. Other apps knows the issuer. these apps validate the token from issuer and if okay, sent secure page to user.

Comment: When i need to use facebook login or google login for example, i must my application on those web sites and they gived me an app-id and a secret that i use them in my code  to add external login. so where is OpenId OAuth integrated in my code ?

Comment: yes, definitely you need to use appid and secret from issuer(fb/google). we just need to configure the middlewear in startup.cs. services.AddAuthentication().AddFacebook(facebookOptions =>
{
    facebookOptions.AppId = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppId"];
    facebookOptions.AppSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppSecret"];
}); Middlewear follows the oauth2 protocol for token vaidation.

Comment: Here is the oauth2.0 doc, if needed https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749

Comment: And openid extends oauth. here is the docs. https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html

Comment: In given code, the middlewear follows the OAuth2 protocol, where is OpenId in this code ?, we just configured the appid and the secret.

Comment: You need to specify openid in scope while requesting. Example: `GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&response_type=id_token
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
&response_mode=form_post
&scope=openid
&state=12345
&nonce=678910`  Here is details https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols and Example App: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/1-WebApp-OIDC. Check startup.cs files.

Comment: So the OpenId is The id provided by the remote site like Google, Facebook and OAuth is the communication protocol used to authenticate a client application like the WebAPI in a remote site. And OpenId and OAuth are used together and cannot be used separated. I'm i right ?

Comment: As openid is built using oauth, it comes togather. You implement oauth seperately according to RFC (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749) if you need.